# Conectar SQL Server 2008 R2 a PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Hola buenas tardes a todos, estoy cambiando mi conexion de mysql a sqlserver, tengo mi codigo de conexion pero no consigo que fucione. Alguien puede ayudarme. Os dejo mi codigo de conexion.

```
<?php
 class Conectar{
        public function conexion(){
            $serverName = "localhost\MSSQLSERVER";
            $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"gestor", 
                            "UID" =>"sa", 
                            "PWD"=>"egestion", 
                            "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");

    $conexion = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if( $conexion ){
     echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
    return $conexion;
        }
}

?>
```

Comment: Obtienes algún error en consola ? o que mensaje te genera ?